# Starting up with Luaj

Tags: java, lua, luaj, luajava

Are there any good Luaj tutorials?
I have been working on a game using Lua for for mi finals but my profesor wants me to implement my code to
java.

I already read the Luaj manual but i found it quite confusing and i need to implement mi lua code quickly

Comment: Why? Your professor wants you to implement your code in Java. Obviously, I don't know your professor; but if I were your professor, I would fail you if your assignment to implement a project in Java used the least possible Java to use Lua instead.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - He permitted the usage of Lua and other languages as while as we interpreted the code on Java

Comment: This doesnt make sense imo either, but anyways, did you try https://github.com/luaj/luaj#run-a-script-in-a-java-application and what was the problem? The lua code stays pretty much the same, and executing it within java doesnt seem complicated either. Where are you stuck?